# Weird UITableView insert/delete row animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation

I'm seeing a weird effect when inserting/deleting a UITableViewCell in a UITableView with animation (UITableViewRowAnimationTop).

The animation glitch happens when the cell to insert is much bigger than the cell above.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YTHu9u88_Y&feature=youtu.be) shows the glitch in the simulator, yellow cell appears suddenly out of no where when it's supposed to slide from top.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ykrg8swfb0lkxe5/TableViewTest.zip) is the Xcode project from the video.

Bellow is the cell insertion/animation code.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2 + self.thirdCellVisible;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if (self.thirdCellVisible)
        {
            self.thirdCellVisible = !self.thirdCellVisible;
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.thirdCellIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        }
        else
        {
            self.thirdCellVisible = !self.thirdCellVisible;
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.thirdCellIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        }
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == self.thirdCellIndexPath.row)
    {
        return 100.0f;
    }

    return 44.0f;
}
```

Comment: The link to the project was apparently deleted. Can you put it back up?

Comment: @Sheamus You can easily regenerate in the code. Try inserting a cell in UITableView which has dynamic rows.

Comment: @Nicholas : You will have to call `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]` before and after calling insert/delete methods respectively.

Comment: @kidsid49: My answer is below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to call

```
[tableView beginUpdates]
```

and

```
[tableView endUpdates]
```

before and after calling insert/delete methods as below :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2 + self.thirdCellVisible;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if (self.thirdCellVisible)
        {
            self.thirdCellVisible = !self.thirdCellVisible;
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];

            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.thirdCellIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

            [self.tableView endUpdates];

        }
        else
        {
            self.thirdCellVisible = !self.thirdCellVisible;
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.thirdCellIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

            [self.tableView endUpdates];

        }
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == self.thirdCellIndexPath.row)
    {
        return 100.0f;
    }

    return 44.0f;
}
```

Comment: Why? There is no batch insertion or deletion being done.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html):

> To animate a batch insertion, deletion, and reloading of rows and
>   sections, call the corresponding methods within an animation block
>   defined by successive calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates. If you
>   don’t call the insertion, deletion, and reloading methods within this
>   block, row and section indexes may be invalid. Calls to beginUpdates
>   and endUpdates can be nested; all indexes are treated as if there were
>   only the outer update block.
>
> At the conclusion of a block—that is, after endUpdates returns—the
>   table view queries its data source and delegate as usual for row and
>   section data. Thus the collection objects backing the table view
>   should be updated to reflect the new or removed rows or sections.

You will have to call `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]` before and after calling insert/delete methods respectively.

An example is provided by Apple on the above link.

*Note*: If your array and table view items are out of sync, without the begin/end calls an exception will be thrown.

*Suggestion*: Try first `withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic`

Comment: But the OP isn't doing a batch insertion, deletion, or reload. They are only doing a single insert or delete. So using `beginUpdates` or `endUpdates` isn't needed.

Comment: The method **[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.thirdCellIndexPath]** accepts an array of indexpaths, so this is a bath insertion.

Comment: No, it's a batch if you make multiple calls to insertRows/deleteRows/reloadRows.

Comment: That discussion doesn't apply here. The OP is only inserting or deleting a single row. One row isn't a batch.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link of video of my working code: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30316681/480.mov

Below is my working code:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL thirdCellVisible;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *thirdCellIndexPath;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.thirdCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2 + self.thirdCellVisible;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == self.thirdCellIndexPath.row)
    {
        return 100.0f;
    }

    return 44.0f;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if (self.thirdCellVisible)
        {
            self.thirdCellVisible = !self.thirdCellVisible;
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.thirdCellIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        }
        else
        {
            self.thirdCellVisible = !self.thirdCellVisible;
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.thirdCellIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        }
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"id";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }

    NSString *cellTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = cellTitle;

    if(indexPath.row == 2)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    else
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use   `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]` as follow

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if (self.thirdCellVisible)
        {
            self.thirdCellVisible = !self.thirdCellVisible;

            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.thirdCellIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
             [self.tableView endUpdates];

        }
        else
        {
            self.thirdCellVisible = !self.thirdCellVisible;

            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.thirdCellIndexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
             [self.tableView endUpdates];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? There is no batch insertion or deletion being done.