# UITableview insert/delete row animation glitch

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have different sections and rows. Each row has a variable height. I am expanding and collapsing the table by inserting and deleting row. But when i expand/collapse, the other cells overlaps with each other causing a glitch.

```
func expandItemAtIndex(index:Int) {
  var indexPaths = NSMutableArray()
  var currentSubItems = contentsArray.objectAtIndex(index) as NSArray
  var insertPos = 0
  for(var i = 0; i < currentSubItems.count; i++) {
    indexPaths.addObject(NSIndexPath(forRow: insertPos++, inSection: index))
  }
  self.tableview.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}

func collapseItemAtIndex(index: Int) {
  var indexPaths = NSMutableArray()
  for (var i = 0; i <  contentsArray.objectAtIndex(index).count; i++) {
    indexPaths.addObject(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: index))
  }

  self.tableview.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}

func expandOrCollapseCells(object:AnyObject) {
  self.tableview.beginUpdates()
  if (expandedIndex[index] == index) {
    self.collapseItemAtIndex(expandedIndex[index])
    expandedIndex[index] = -1
  } else {
    expandedIndex[index] = index
    self.expandItemAtIndex(expandedIndex[index])
  }
  self.tableview.endUpdates()

  if (self.tableview.numberOfRowsInSection(index) > 0) {
    self.tableview.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: index), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
  }
}
```

I am calling `expandOrCollapseCells` when the header is tapped.

You can find similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021506/weird-uitableview-insert-delete-row-animation)

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YTHu9u88_Y

Comment: WIthout code, it will be hard for anyone to debug.

Comment: @LordZsolt: I updated question with code. Please have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you aren't using Swift 3 due to the syntax differences.

The one thing that really sticks out is this line:
`self.tableview.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)`

Have you tried using `UITableViewRowAnimation.Top` instead?

Because it seems to me like the "animation" visible in the video is being forced by beginUpdates() and endUpdates(), since the animation value is set to `None` in the actual method.

I'd also not recommend using another cell to expand/collapse content from any given cell if you don't specifically need the expanded content to be a table cell for some reason. If that isn't the case, then I'd suggest laying out the expanded content in the parent level cell structure and simply hiding/unhiding it as needed.